# Show that if $x_n → x $ in $(X, d_X )$ and $f : (X, d_X ) → (Y, d_Y )$ is continuous then $f(x_n) → f(x) $ in $(Y, d_Y)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Show that if $x_n → x $ in $(X, d_X )$ and $f : (X, d_X ) → (Y, d_Y )$ is continuous then $f(x_n) → f(x) $ in $(Y, d_Y)$.

I want to prove this using open sets, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: I mean, obviously you want to use open sets. Hint: write down the definition of convergence in a metric space for a sequence of points, and a sequence of functions. It should become obvious then

Comment: I was told there was another way to do it and to specifically use open sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$ and consider the open ball $B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$. Since it is an open set and $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}\left(B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right)$ is an open subset of $X$ and it is trivial that $x$ belongs to it. Since it is an open subset of $X$ and $x$ belongs to it, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x)\subset f^{-1}\left(B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right)$. And there is a natural $N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n\in B_\delta(x)$. But then$$n\geqslant N\implies f(x_n)\in B_\varepsilon\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\iff d\bigl(f(x_n),f(x)\bigr)<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I am unsure in general of this whole thing so not really, although I understand what you have said here. How do I show convergence from here?

Comment: I have completed the proof. Is it clear now?

Comment: Got you, appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous, for any neighbourhood $\mathrm{V}$ of $f(x),$ the set $\mathrm{U} = f^{-1}(\mathrm{V})$ is a neighbourhood of $x,$ as such, for some $N \in \mathbf{N},$ all $x_n \in \mathrm{U}$ provided $n \geq N.$ Q.E.D.